# Как вычислить размер переменной если неизвестен её начальный тип?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть переменная тип которой известен только в начале работы приложения, в дальнейшем указатель на неё благополучно преобразуется в `void*` и передается дальше по ветке методов, и вот после преобразования мне надо как-то вычислить её размер. Есть sizeof, но он в данном случае бесполезен.

Существует-ли метод чтобы узнать размер подобной преобразованной переменной?

Comment: Нет, нужно таскать с собой и тип/размер. Но откуда такая задача? Преобразование в `void*` - чисто C'шная идиома. Вы же в С++ - почему не воспользоваться другими способами? Какая задача у вас *изначально*, может, саму задачу можно решить лучше и проще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не существует. Необходимо хранить информацию о типе или/и о размере типа.

Похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/1718412.

Answer (score 0):

создай переменную в самом начале `varSize = sizeof(var);` а потом используй